# WS-Federation Azure AD On-Behalf-Of flow

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, ws-federation

I'm using WS-Federation with Azure AD as in the below code. I'm also using cookie authentication.

```
            services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
            {
                sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                sharedOptions.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = WsFederationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, authenticationOptions =>
            {
                authenticationOptions.Cookie.Name = "access_token";
            })
            .AddWsFederation(config =>
            {
                config.Wtrealm = options.Realm;
                config.MetadataAddress = options.MetadataAddress;
                config.Events.OnAuthenticationFailed = (context) =>
                {
                    context.HandleResponse();
                    context.Response.Redirect(options.FailedAuthRedirectUrl);
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                };
                config.SaveTokens = true;
            });
```

The problem I have is that in order to implement on-behalf-of flow i.e I want to generate a new token for another Web API service based on the current token used by the web app. I'm following https://dzimchuk.net/using-the-on-behalf-of-flow-in-your-aspnet-core-services-protected-by-azure-ad/.

I need the original token to create a UserAssertion:

```
 if (HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
             var originalToken = await httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Authentication.GetTokenAsync("access_token");
        }
```

originalToken is always null however, I've tried many combinations of Scheme name and cookie name. I can see there's a cookie in the request called "access_token". Will this approach never work with WS-Federation and cookies?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are using WS-Fed? I have an example on how to do this with OAuth/OIDC: https://joonasw.net/view/azure-ad-on-behalf-of-aspnet-core

Comment: And by the way, the cookie name has nothing to do with that parameter. The "access_token" string is hard-coded into the OAuth Bearer auth middleware.

Comment: Hi, there's no reason in particular other than legacy code and I'm using Azure AD single sign-on. I've changed WS-Fed to OpenIdConnect and now have access to the id_token but that doesn't work with jwt I have read. I'm following your blog, can I use jwt bearer authentication with AAD? Thanks for your help

Comment: Yeah, you can use Bearer tokens for APIs. OpenID Connect is for UI applications anyway.

Comment: But if in this case you have a user and this is not an API, you don't need on-behalf-of :) You can get an access token with Authorization Code flow or Implicit flow if you have a Single Page JS app.

Comment: The reason I need on-behalf-of is because I want to be able to call out to Web API end points secured with jwt

Comment: To call an API, you need an access token. There are many flows available that allow you to get one. On-behalf-of is one of them. It is used when you have an API (secured with JWT tokens) and you need to call another API from that API, while still calling that as the same user.

Comment: My plan now is to use OpenID to produce an access_token available to from angular to access and API secured with jwt. The problem I have that I have followed your blog https://joonasw.net/view/aspnet-core-2-azure-ad-authentication it authenticates and logs in and produces an id_token but no access_token.

Comment: OnAuthorizationCodeReceived never fires